# Image size difference between chrome and internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am making a simple website addition for images, but the size on internet explorer 11 is being computed to be much smaller, and changes between images:

[internet explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF04W.jpg)

but works fine on chrome

[chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDYY7.jpg)

Here is the css for the image:

```
.postImage {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;  
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May have nothing to do with the code you posted, but rather another element that contains the post image.  Are you using a `div` with the `flex` property per chance?

Comment: Yes I am, one of the parent elements uses display:flex

Comment: Try adding `min-height: 1px` to the flex item and see if that fixes it.  You may also want to ref https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75

Comment: I tried doing all the methods mentioned in this thread and still no luck, but it most likely is something related to this bug. I'll let you know if I figure it out, thanks so much for pointing me towards this!

Comment: No problem.  If you figure it out, please definitely share.  Helps the whole community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after tinkering around with it a bit and getting help from [here](http://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75), I got it working across browsers. It seems strange since I am setting height twice, but it is the only way that worked as I expected it to for IE11.

parent class:

```
.postBox{
  height: 100px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  display: flex;
  cursor :pointer;

  /* to fix IE11 */
    min-height:1px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
}
```

Child image class:

```
.postImage {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;  
  border-radius: 2px;

/*   to fix IE11 not working */
  max-height:50px;
  max-width:50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```